# How to use Google App Script to send a file using POST request

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, http-post, urlfetch

I want to use Google Apps Script to integrate a Google Sheets with an API

This is the documentation from the API service:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://apinew.socialhub.pro/api/sendMessage' \
--form 'api_token="SEU API_TOKEN AQUI"' \
--form 'phone="NUMERO DESTINO"' \
--form 'file=@"DIRETÓRIO DO ARQUIVO"' \
--form 'message="MENSAGEM"'
```

I have manage to create a script in Google App Script that works perfectly:

```
function send_message_teste(telephone,message) {
  var url = "https://apinew.socialhub.pro/api/sendMessage";
  
  telephone = telephone.toString();
  
  let request = {
                  "api_token":"MY_TOKEN",
                  "phone":telephone,
                  "message":message
                };
                
  let resquest_body = JSON.stringify(request);

  let config = {
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    payload:resquest_body
  };
               

  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, config);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  
  return response
}
```

My problem is that I can not make this work with a file. The API documentation has only the curl example. I have manage to translate this example to Google App Script, but I got stuck when trying to send a file through the API. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried using `post` method in your apps script instead of `get` since what you want to do is to send a file and not get a file? It is already in your postman code.

Comment: The API seems to work when i use `get` or 'post`, when I am not trying to use the `file` parameter. But when I try to send the `file` parameter it does not work. The error is the same with `post` or with `get`.

Comment: Did you try to convert the file into a `blob` before adding it to your `post` request?

Comment: I did... but I passed the file inside the request object. Someone suggested sending it inside another object. I will try that and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert the following curl command to Google Apps Script.

  ```bash
  curl --location --request POST 'https://apinew.socialhub.pro/api/sendMessage' \
  --form 'api_token="SEU API_TOKEN AQUI"' \
  --form 'phone="NUMERO DESTINO"' \
  --form 'file=@"DIRETÓRIO DO ARQUIVO"' \
  --form 'message="MENSAGEM"'
  ```

I thought that when I saw your curl command, the request is `multipart/form-data`. But, in your showing script, it seems that the value is sent ad JSON data. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. When this is reflected in a sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please set the file ID of your file on Google Drive to `fileId`.

```js
function send_message_teste(telephone,message) {
  const fileId = "###"; // Please set your file ID of the file you want to upload.

  var url = "https://apinew.socialhub.pro/api/sendMessage";
  telephone = telephone.toString();
  let request = {
    "api_token": "MY_TOKEN",
    "phone": telephone,
    "message": message
  };
  const payload = { ...request, file: DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob() };
  let config = { muteHttpExceptions: true, payload };
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, config);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  return response;
}
```

- When `payload` is included, the POST method is automatically used.

#### Note:

- I think that the request of this modified script is the same with the above curl command. But, if an error occurs, please confirm your values of `request` and `fileId`, again.
- If the structure of `multipart/form-data` of this modified script cannot be used in your API, this Google Apps Script library might be able to be used. [Ref (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/FetchApp)

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: This might be a dumb question, I know, but this `...` you put before the `...request` variable does something?

Comment: By the way, your code worked perfectly!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you so much!!!! I still do not understand exactly what the `...` operator does, but the code works!

Comment: @user3347814 It's a spread operator. You can look it up in mdn.

Comment: @user3347814 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: I have never seen this operator, in this case, is it the same thing as adding another key to the object?

Comment: @user3347814 About `in this case, is it the same thing as adding another key to the object?`, it's yes. For example, when there is `const a = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}`, `const res = {...a, "key3": "value3"}` becomes `{key1: "value1", key2: "value2", "key3": "value3"}`.